# How to develop schedular to get last 24 hours woo-Commerce Sales report

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using `WC_Report_Sales_By_Date` function can easily get a WooCommerce sales report, but I need a scheduler to get a daily report in CSV format in 24 hour intervals and save in a local repository.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event). These can be fired hourly, twice daily, or daily (or a custom interval).

As an example, add this to your `functions.php` file - the `vnmReport_createDailyReport` function should then be fired every day at around midnight:

```
<?php

function vnmActivationFunction() {

    $midnight = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00');

    if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_hourly_event')) {
        wp_schedule_event($midnight, 'daily', 'vnmReport_saveDailyReport');
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'vnmActivationFunction');

function vnmReport_createDailyReport() {

    include_once( WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-admin-report.php' );
    include_once( WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-sales-by-date.php' );

    $report = new WC_Report_Sales_By_Date();
    $results = $report->get_report_data();

}

add_action('vnmReport_DailyReport', 'vnmReport_createDailyReport');

?>
```

`$results` will be a `stdClass` object that you can then do whatever is needed to create your CSV and then output/save that to disk.

It's worth noting that `wp_schedule_event` uses `wp_cron`, which doesn't fire the same way as a traditional crontab; it fires as soon as it can the next time there's activity on the site; so if it's set to fire daily at midnight, but there's no activity on your site (front end or back) until 1am, that's when the event will be fired.